# Xcode 6.4 - Can't Open Another Device in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, xcode6.4

I have built and ran my application on the simulator's iPhone 6 device. Now that I want to run on another device for testing my code and I keep getting the below error. Has something changed in Xcode 6.4 or iOS 8 which requires me to do another step before changing devices?

Error:

> **Simulator in Use**
>
> Xcode cannot launch apps on the simulated device “iPad Air”, as it is
>   currently running an app on “iPhone 6”. Only one simulated device may
>   be used at a time

[image: Simulator in Use Error]

I've already tried removing the app from the simulator, quitting the simulator, reseting contents and settings...

Comment: clean all your project and then try

Comment: Did you restart xcode?

Comment: Quit xcode and simulator and reopen it it will help

Comment: Well I'll be damnnneedd... Quitting Xcode helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Quitting Xcode and restarting the app helped solve the issue.

Thanks @baydi & @t4nhpt